# Create a subshell under node that can be used like a normal shell

Tags: node.js

So, I want to do some setup and create an environment to run various commands using node.  Doing in this in python or from a shell works simply (and maybe that's the best answer) but for various reasons using node has advantages.  I've tried various permutations of spawn but everything is failing in different ways.  This might be the closest I've gotten.

```
$ node
> const { spawn } = require('child_process');
undefined
> const ignore = spawn('/bin/zsh', ['--no-rcs'],
      { stdio:'inherit', detached: true, env: {...process.env, 'PS1': 'Subshell> ' }}
).on('code', () => console.log('done'))
undefined
> %
Subshell> ls
Thrown:
ReferenceError: l is not defined
>sls
zsh: command not found: sl
Subshell>
```

But, not really that close.

Comment: There is this issue, https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21664.

Comment: The interactive `node` process and the spawned `zsh` are both trying to read from the same, shared standard input stream (which is attached to the terminal).  They'll each get some of the characters that are typed in, and the result is a mess.  Instead of prototyping it this way, write your program into a file and tell `node` to run that file.  Then `node` won't be trying to read from the terminal, so `zsh` will get all of the characters.

Comment: I'll try that - maybe my issues are that simple, @ottomeister

Comment: Maybe try out [node-pty](https://npmjs.com/package/node-pty)